Авторизация через Google с использованием authlib (Ошибка: CSRF Warning! State not equal in request and response)
У меня есть две ручки, написанные на FastAPI.
@router.get('')
async def google_auth(request: Request):
    redirect_uri = request.url_for('google_login')
    state = secrets.token_urlsafe(8)
    request.session['state'] = state
    redirect_uri = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/auth/login'
    return await google.auth(request, redirect_uri, state = state)


@router.get('/login', include_in_schema = False)
async def google_login(request: Request):
    state = request.session.pop('state', None)
    google_state = request.query_params.get('state')
    try: 
        google_access_token = await google.get_access_token(request)
        userdata = google.get_userdata(google_access_token)
        schemas = UserServices.google_login(userdata)
        
        access_token, refresh_token = auth.create_access_and_refresh_token(schemas)
        auth.save_tokens(schemas.uuid, request, access_token, refresh_token)

        return templates.TemplateResponse(request, 'success_login.html')
    
    except:
        return templates.TemplateResponse(request, 'fail_login.html')

Если в гугле ввести ссылку на ручку "google_auth" авторизация произойдет успешно. Но если я перенаправлю с react приложения на эту ручку, то получу ошибку:
authlib.integrations.base_client.errors.MismatchingStateError: mismatching_state: CSRF Warning! State not equal in request and response.

Почему-то state сохранненый в ручке google_auth в ручке google_login не будет его.
Вот как я перенаправляю пользователя на авторизацию:
export default function Login() {

    function redirectToLogin() {
        window.location.href = loginURL
    }

    if (afterLoginURL != window.location.href){
        return (
            <>
            <Header/>
            <div style={{textAlign: 'center'}}>
              <h1>Необходимо авторизоваться</h1>
              <button onClick={redirectToLogin} className="btn btn-success">Авторизоваться</button>
            </div>
            </>
        )
    } 

Вот еще код (он используется для работы с библиотекой authlib):
from starlette.config import Config
from authlib.integrations.starlette_client import OAuth
import requests

config = Config('../.env')
oauth = OAuth(config = config)


class Google:
    
    def __init__(
        self,
        client_id: str,
        client_secret: str,
    ):
        
        self.client_id = client_id,
        self.client_secret = client_secret
        self.google = oauth.register(
            name='google',
            client_id=client_id,
            client_secret=client_secret,
            access_token_url='https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',
            access_token_params=None,
            authorize_url='https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth',
            authorize_params=None,
            api_base_url='https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/',
            userinfo_endpoint='https://openidconnect.googleapis.com/v1/userinfo',  # This is only needed if using openId to fetch user info
            jwks_uri='https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/certs',  # Add this line

            client_kwargs={'scope': 'openid profile email'},
        )
    
    async def auth(self, request: Request, redirect_uri: str, state: str):
        return await self.google.authorize_redirect(request, redirect_uri, state = state)
    
    
    async def get_access_token(self, request: Request):
        token = await self.google.authorize_access_token(request)
        access_token = token.get('access_token')
        return access_token
    
    def get_userdata(self, access_token: str):
        url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?alt=json'
        headers = {
            "Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}",
            "content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
        }
        
        response = requests.get(url, headers = headers).json()
        userschemas = UserCreateSchemas(
            username = response.get('name'),
            email = response.get('email'),
            google_access_token = access_token,
            picture = response.get('picture')
        )
        return userschemas
    

google = Google(
    client_id = settings.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
    client_secret = settings.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
)

В итоге почему не сохраняется state в сессии, если я перенаправляю на ссылку ручки через js (react). И как это исправить?
